# HSQLDB remove generated constraints referencing to other table

Tags: sql, constraints, database-schema, hsqldb

In the database scheme there are some cyclic references. It causes problems. References are created by provider using generated names:

```
alter table users add constraint FK_olm1qeb13uc1worutbx1sc22k foreign key (USER_ID) references user_settings
alter table user_settings add constraint FK_3ry0dxqxek7eg9frxr6bpofr9 foreign key (USER_ID) references users
```

I need a solution that is described here, [but for MsSql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641954/how-to-drop-column-with-constraint#answer-13715343).
Is there a way in HSQLDB to remove all constraints of concrete type (foreign key (USER_ID) references) when I know only table name?

Without writing stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Use a query on INFORMATION_SCHEMA to find the names of constraints used on a particular table:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'USERS'
```

Comment: I need a way to drop constraints via script. not just a simple query that returns constraint names.just like the answer like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641954/how-to-drop-column-with-constraint#answer-13715343