# Error while dropping a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just created a table as below in MS SQL

```
create table Employee 
(emp_id smallint not null,
employee_name varchar (30) not null,
salary money not null,
department varchar(30),
address varchar(40),
primary key(emp_id)
)
```

After creating the table, I feel like auto populating the emp_id column( using Identity). So, I was trying to drop the column emp_id as below:

```
alter table Employee 
drop column emp_id
```

Even though, I haven't inserted any rows in the table yet, I am getting the error

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The object
>   'PK__Employee__1299A86183CA4FBC' is dependent on column 'emp_id'. Msg
>   4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1 ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN emp_id failed
>   because one or more objects access this column.

Please help!!!

Comment: HI it is because the column you are doping has been  referenced in other table . If you really want to drop it please first drop the constraint and then drop the column .

Comment: `emp_id` is your primary key as in your create table query `primary key(emp_id)` so you should drop that Primary Key constraint before drop that column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drop column with constraint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641954/how-to-drop-column-with-constraint)

Comment: Thanks Yashveer..I did the same and it worked..

Comment: TIP: When adding constraints such as your PK, it helps to give it an explicit name rather than allowing a derived random name to be generated.

Comment: In fact there is 43 question with "ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because one or more objects access this column.".

Answer (score 2):

Something like this can help .

```
   ALTER TABLE Employee   
   DROP CONSTRAINT PK__Employee__1299A86183CA4FBC; 


   alter table Employee 
   drop column emp_id
```

Comment: So the Idea is first drop all constraint like primary keys / FK etc and then alter the table

Comment: NOTE: When re-adding the column, you'd need to re-add the PK as well.

Comment: @CraigYoung :- Thanks I missed to inform that it will make answer more useful .

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by executing below query: I need to remove a column and all the entries from that column to free my DB size my initial table structure is as shown below:

***CREATE TABLE words(_id,word,synonyms,favorite,history,updDate)***

And I wanted the table in below form

***CREATE TABLE words(_id,word,favorite,history,updDate)***

So I executed below query and it removed "synonyms" column

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1_backup(_id,word,favorite,history,updDate);
INSERT INTO t1_backup SELECT _id,word,favorite,history,updDate FROM words;
DROP TABLE words;
CREATE TABLE words(_id,word,favorite,history,updDate);
INSERT INTO words SELECT _id,word,favorite,history,updDate FROM t1_backup;
DROP TABLE t1_backup
COMMIT;
```