# Can't drop a column with a constraint in command line

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an `exercises` table with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE exercises
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    workoutID INTEGER NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (workoutID) REFERENCES workouts(id)
);
```

I want to delete the column `workoutID` but it won't let me delete it:

```
sqlite> ALTER TABLE exercises DROP workoutID;
```

> Error: near "DROP": syntax error

Upon realizing I need to remove the constraints first I try:

```
sqlite> ALTER TABLE exercises DROP CONSTRAINT workoutID;
```

> Error: near "DROP": syntax error

I followed this question to the letter: [How to drop column with constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641954/how-to-drop-column-with-constraint)
But it doesn't work for me.

I can start over by dropping the whole table if I have to but I want to learn why this isn't working for me.

Any help and explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884787/how-do-i-drop-a-constraint-from-a-sqlite-3-6-21-table

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been dropping tables for a month now because I couldn't find a way to do this. I finally asked the question because I knew there had to be a way. Can you change your comment to an answer so I can approve it as an answer?