# sql server drop default syntax error

Tags: sql-server-2005, constraints

I am trying to drop the default value on a bit column, I have set it wrong and I want to do it again correctly.  However, when I write:

```
ALTER TABLE Person
ALTER COLUMN tsHomePref DROP DEFAULT;
```

I get a 'incorrect syntax near keyword default error' and I don't know why

I want to drop the column and then build it again

```
ALTER TABLE Person
ADD COLUMN tsHomePref bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

So, why won't it let me 'drop' the default value?

Thanks R.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you drop a default value or similar constraint in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123060/how-do-you-drop-a-default-value-or-similar-constraint-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to do

```
ALTER TABLE Person 
    DROP CONSTRAINT DF__Person__tsHomePr__05BA7BDB
```

It helps if you use a consistent naming convention for these so you don't have to look in the system tables to get the name first.

Comment: Yep, this worked and I was able to add the column with the default value that I wanted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know the name of the constraint ( as I didn't know today when searching for a solution to the same problem ), you can use the following for Ms Sqlserver:

```
DECLARE @defname VARCHAR(100), @cmd VARCHAR(1000)
SET @defname =
   (SELECT name FROM sysobjects so
     JOIN sysconstraints sc ON so.id = sc.constid
   WHERE object_name(so.parent_obj) = 'TableName'
     AND sc.colid = 
         (SELECT colid FROM syscolumns WHERE id = object_id('dbo.TableName') AND name = 'FieldName'))
    SET @cmd = 'ALTER TABLE TableName DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @defname
   EXEC(@cmd)
GO
```

This worked in my case. Hope it helps others as well.